# Combine Results from different row

Tags: mysql, sql

We have a table with the following fields:

```
date/time          user        callTimeToAnswer   CallSequence
2013-11-01 15:37 | SysAnswer | 17               | 56
2013-11-01 15:38 | Jo        | 3                | 56
2013-11-01 15:38 | Fred      | 17               | 59
```

What I am trying to do is to combine any results where the callSequence field is the same. So in the example, I want to combine the field callTimeToAnswer from the first row with the results from the second row, using the field CallSequence. Giving me:

```
2013-11-01 15:38 | Jo        | 3                | 56 | 17
```

Is there any way to combine the two?

Many thanks

Comment: What would the output be if there are more than 2 with the same CallSequence?

Comment: Why do you need it as a separate column? What if there're more than two calls in a sequence?

Comment: Both good points. I have not seen the system record more than two rows for each sequence. What I am trying to do is to get the callToAnswer from the SysAnswer row and add it to other rows with the same sequence. As the other rows numbers are incorrect.

Comment: datetimes are stored using a proper date/time data type, right? And it's not exactly a representative data set is it? How about some proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) TOGETHER WITH A CORRESPONDING RESULT SET.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Too many things are still unclear with your question but to get the desired output you showed and taking into account your comments you can do

```sql
SELECT t1.*, t2.callTimeToAnswer callTimeToAnswer2
  FROM table1 t1 JOIN table1 t2
    ON t1.CallSequence = t2.CallSequence
   AND t1.datetime > t2.datetime;
```

Output:

```
|                        DATETIME | USER | CALLTIMETOANSWER | CALLSEQUENCE | CALLTIMETOANSWER2 |
|---------------------------------|------|------------------|--------------|-------------------|
| November, 01 2013 15:38:00+0000 |   Jo |                3 |           56 |                17 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/69a1f0/6)** demo